# Django - OpenID & OAuth

Tags: django, oauth, openid

I have an application running on Django.
I'd like to be able to authenticate/authorize users from at least Facebook, Google, Yahoo.
We can find [many applications](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoResources#Djangoapplicationcomponents) to manage identity providers in the internet.
I found several answers on stackoverflow but suggestions all seem to be quite old.

The question is: what is the simplest/best maintained solution available ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth)

Comment: The shortest and most complete answer :D

Comment: @MartinThurau: as long as the link is not broken

Comment: Update: "NOTE: THIS LIBRARY IS DEPRECATED IN FAVOR OF `python-social-auth`. RIGHT NOW THIS LIBRARY DEPENDS DIRECTLY ON `python-social-auth` AND SHOULD BE CONSIDERED AS A MIGRATION STEP" Link: https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth